# How to import artifacts, describe, it from Truffle

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, truffle-deployment

Instead of using `truffle deploy`, I want to create my own `deploy.js` script and run it using `node deploy.js`.

How can I import the classes/functions `artifacts`, `describe` and `it`, so we can do like so:

```
var Foo = artifacts.require('./Foo');

describe('Deploying', async () => {
    it('Deploying Foo', async () => {
        let foo = await Foo.new()   
    })  
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `describe`, `it` and so forth, for this specific purpose.

These entities are part of the [Mocha Framework](https://mochajs.org/), designated for testing, not for production.

For deployment, you can simply write your code and run it with NodeJS.

Note that you will have to `require(web3)` and instantiate it yourself, since Truffle will no longer "be there" to do it for you.

Also note that you will have to add `web3` to your `npm` installation file (`package.json`), so that you can import it.

Also note that while you'd probably want to install the latest version of this module (currently `web3@1.0.0-beta.34`), Truffle still uses `web3@0.18.4`. And unfortunately, there are many breaking changes between the two versions, so you will have to interact with `web3` different from what you're probably used to (unless you stick to `web3@0.18.4` in your `npm` installation file).

Here is an example of a deployment script using `web3@1.0.0-beta.34`:

```
let fs = require("fs");
let Web3 = require("web3");

let CLIENT_URL     = process.argv[2];
let GAS_PRICE      = process.argv[3];
let OWNER_ADDRESS  = process.argv[4];
let OWNER_PASSWORD = process.argv[5];

let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(CLIENT_URL));

async function call(transaction) {
    let success = await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(OWNER_ADDRESS, OWNER_PASSWORD);
    let gas = await transaction.estimateGas({from: OWNER_ADDRESS, gasPrice: GAS_PRICE});
    return await transaction.call({from: OWNER_ADDRESS, gasPrice: GAS_PRICE, gas: gas});
}

async function send(transaction) {
    let success = await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(OWNER_ADDRESS, OWNER_PASSWORD);
    let gas = await transaction.estimateGas({from: OWNER_ADDRESS, gasPrice: GAS_PRICE});
    return await transaction.send({from: OWNER_ADDRESS, gasPrice: GAS_PRICE, gas: gas});
}

async function deploy(contractName, contractArgs) {
    let abi = fs.readFileSync("../build/binaries/" + contractName + ".abi").toString();
    let bin = fs.readFileSync("../build/binaries/" + contractName + ".bin").toString();
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));
    let handle = await send(contract.deploy({data: "0x" + bin, arguments: contractArgs}));
    console.log(`${contractName} contract deployed at address ${handle._address}`);
    return handle;
}

async function run() {
    let arg1 = ...;
    let arg2 = ...;
    let arg3 = ...;
    let myContract = await deploy("MyContract", [arg1, arg2]);
    let retval  = await call(myContract.methods.func1(arg3));
    let receipt = await send(myContract.methods.func2(arg3));
}

run();
```